# Trying to change the value of a global variable, variable is undefined error in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react, and wanted to make a shopping website. I created a global array named cart, and I can read the data in it. However, when I tried to update the data in the cart array, I encountered with the error "ReferenceError: cart is not defined"

```
const [cartProducts, setCartProducts] = useState(cart);

const handleCartButton = () => {
    if(!cartProducts.includes({item})) // itemi içerse de buraya giriyor.
    {
        const newList = cartProducts.concat( [{item}] );
        setCartProducts(newList);
    }
    cart = cartProducts; // this is the error line
}
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(item.name + cartProducts);    
    console.log(cart);    
},[cartProducts])
```

and this is the cart array,

```
export let cart = [];
```

I do not know how to update a global variable.

Comment: Can you post the code which includes cart array?

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
You try to assign a value to `const` variable. Try changing it to `let cart = []`

Comment: I edited and posted it.

Comment: I changed const to let, but it is still undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For global variables you should use `context`

```
// AppContext.js

import React, { useContext } from "react"

const AppContext = React.createContext()

export const AppProvider = ({
    children
}) => {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

    const value = { cart, setCart }

    return <IconContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</IconContext.Provider>
}

export function useAppContext() {
    return useContext(AppContext)
}
```

And then use it like this (from your example):

```
// make sure to import useAppContext
const { cart, setCart } = useAppContext()

const handleCartButton = () => {
    if(!cart.includes({item})) {
        const newList = cart.concat( [{item}] );
        setCart(newList);
    }
}

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(item.name + cart);    
    console.log(cart);    
},[cart])
```

And then make sure to wrap your component in AppProvider:

```
import React from "react"
import {AppProvider} from "./AppContext.js"

const ParentComponent = () => {
    return <AppProvider>
        <YourComponent/>
    </AppProvider>
}
```

You can wrap your whole application with AppProvider:

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import {AppProvider} from "./AppContext.js"

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root')
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <AppProvider>
        <App />
      </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Now, I encountered with this error: "Cannot destructure property 'cart' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined"

Comment: Make sure to wrap your application with AppProvider

Comment: I put quotation marks inside React.createContext(), and the problem is fixed, thank you for your nice answer.